# How can I download PayPal giving fund transactions?

Tags: paypal

I am managing a PayPal charity account which is also listed in PayPal giving fund. We receive funds monthly in a fixed date from PayPal. I am trying to get the list of donations in a csv file so that I can update our app to send acknowledgement email. Currently, I can download the csv from https://www.paypal.com/us/givingfund/activity. But, this csv file does not have correct transaction dates. It has the date on which we received the fund, which is same for all transactions in that month. Is there a link where I can download a csv file of the transactions with correct transaction/donation date?